# Is there a way to add a scroll bar to Python Folium Popups?

Tags: python, folium

I want to add API data to the Folium Popup but there's too much data to fit in one popup. I would like to add a scroll bar but there does not seem to be a way to do that unlike in leaflet javascript.

Comment: This [example](https://nbviewer.org/github/python-visualization/folium/blob/main/examples/Popups.ipynb) specifies an IFrame as a popup. Changing the height of this example from 300px to 100px will automatically display a vertical scroll bar. Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: use an iframe object and add it to the folium.popup object.
example:

import branca

iframe = branca.element.IFrame(html='hello world' , width=500,height=400)

popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=500 )

this example code automatically adds a scroll bar. Make sure your iFrame width matches the max width of the folium popup.